# A few problems with a sentence (a tale from circa 1930)

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, literature

Reading an [The Epiphany of Death by Clark Ashton Smith](http://www.eldritchdark.com/writings/short-stories/65/the-epiphany-of-death), I have a problem with the following sentences (because of the context, I pasted also the preceding sentence):

> My memory is not what it was, and there are certain lacunae for which
> my readers must contrive to forgive me. The only wonder is, that my
> powers of recollection have survived at all, beneath the hideous
> burden they have had to bear; for, in a more than metaphoric sense, I
> have been **as one** condemned to **carry with him**, at all times and in all
> places, the loathsome **incubi** of things long dead and corrupt.

The first thing I am not sure of is the "I have been as one condemned". Can the "as" be omitted?

My other problem is "carry with" - it does not seem to be the usual usage, does still mean "carry him with me", as in "still present whenever I go"?

But who is "him"? I thought it refers to the incubus, but as there is the plural, incubi, I do not think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the context:

> in a **more than metaphoric sense**, I have been as one condemned to carry with him the loathsome incubi of things long dead and corrupt.

(for simplicity I've omitted the parenthetic statement "at all times and in all places")

The prefix for the statement in question is that it is *more than a metaphor*. So it *is* a metaphor, but perhaps with some elements having a literal parallel.

A *simile*, which is a type of metaphor, always uses "as" or "like" when drawing a comparison. The writer isn't saying he has *literally* been condemned to carry dead and corrupt things, but that he is *like* (or "as") a man who has. The use of the fantasy creatures "incubi" to describe unpleasant things makes it more obviously metaphorical.

Without the wider context I am guessing, but perhaps the literal aspects of this metaphor (what makes it *more than metaphorical*) relate to him actually carrying things?

Answer (score 3):

*As one condemned* = like a person condemned. *Him* refers to this metaphorical person, condemned always to carry painful memories with him.

Answer (score 1):

Good on you for including the context! It turns out to be important to aid in our understanding of this complex construction. However, with a bit of attention to detail, understanding this is not that difficult.

First, in the opening sentence, consider that the author is asking us, the readers, for our attention and understanding, and setting up what is to follow. Then, with the phrase "*in a more than metaphoric sense*", the author is alerting us that some comparison is about to happen (or has already happened). And, indeed, that is what we immediately find, starting with "*as one*", where *one* is used as a gender-neutral pronoun, which is the subject of the following phrase (a metaphor, or simile)<sup>1</sup>. So let's look at that phrase by itself:

> As one condemned to carry with him, at all times and in all places, the loathsome incubi of things long dead and corrupt.

Since everything in that phrase defines and modifies the subject of the phrase (i.e. the *one*, or *person*), the meaning of the following phrase should now be clear. This person is condemned, but not generically so. This person is "*condemned to carry with him*" incubi (Latin plural of incubus). A bit like Prometheus, the man is condemned to a never-ending task. And so, the author is comparing himself, or more accurately his '*powers of recollection*' with their '*hideous burden*', to a man condemned to a never-ending task of carrying with him pain, evil, and horror in the form of nightmares<sup>2</sup> of, or demons consisting of, dead and corrupt things.

<sup>1</sup>Somewhat archaically, the author uses *him* to refer back to *one* later in the phrase. Gender neutrality was less of a "thing" historically, and using *one*, a gender-neutral pronoun, was more common, with usage falling off in the 20th century. By the latter half of the 20th century, such usage was considered effete. However, with gender-neutrality gaining importance in the beginning of the 21st century, usage of gender-neutral pronouns has increased.

<sup>2</sup>Since this is an older bit of writing, going with a more [archaic sense of incubus](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/incubus) (nightmares) makes more sense, if one is unfamiliar with the word.